# dsPIC33EV256GM002 PWM settings

Tags: microchip, pwm, dspic

I developed a simple program to produce PWM waveform on dsPIC33EV256GM002 but I can't disable it. I used PWM1 and PWM2 and I would generate PWM waveform on PWM1L1 pin (pin 26 on DIP package) maintain PWM1H1 (pin 25 on DIP package) as digital I/O.
Teorically the PWM register setting:
    IOCON1bits.PENL      = 1;   /* PWM1L is controlled by PWM module */ 
    IOCON1bits.PENH      = 0;   /* PWM1H is controlled by GPIO module */
should do that but, using and oscilloscope, I noticed the PWM waveform on PWM1H1 pin, with opposite value (when PWM1L is 1 PWM1H is 0 and veceversa) even if it should be a digital I/O.

Did you find any similar problem ?

Thank you very much for your help and cooperation

regards

I used the following code:

```
TRISBbits.TRISB10 = 0;                  /* Set as a digital output */
TRISBbits.TRISB11 = 0;                  /* Set as a digital output */
TRISBbits.TRISB12 = 0;                  /* Set as a digital output */
TRISBbits.TRISB13 = 0;                  /* Set as a digital output */
TRISBbits.TRISB14 = 0;                  /* Set as a digital output */
TRISBbits.TRISB15 = 0;                  /* Set as a digital output */

LATBbits.LATB10 = 0;                /* Set as a digital output */
LATBbits.LATB11 = 0;                /* Set as a digital output */
LATBbits.LATB12 = 0;                /* Set as a digital output */
LATBbits.LATB13 = 0;                /* Set as a digital output */
LATBbits.LATB14 = 0;                /* Set as a digital output */
LATBbits.LATB15 = 0;                /* Set as a digital output */

  PORTBbits.RB10=0;
  PORTBbits.RB11=0;
  PORTBbits.RB12=0;
  PORTBbits.RB13=0;
  PORTBbits.RB14=0;
  PORTBbits.RB15=0;

  PTPER = 4000; 
/*~~~~~~~~~~ PWM1 Configuration ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/    
IOCON1bits.PENL      = 1;   /* PWM1L is controlled by PWM module */ 
IOCON1bits.PENH      = 0;   /* PWM1H is controlled by GPIO module */
IOCON1bits.PMOD      = 0;   /* Select Independent Output PWM mode */
PDC1 = 500;                 /* Initial Duty cycle */ 
DTR1    = 0;                /* Deadtime setting */
ALTDTR1 = 0;                /* Deadtime setting */
PHASE1 = 0;                 /* No phase shift */

/*~~~~~~~~~~~ PWM2 Configuration ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
IOCON2bits.PENH      = 1;  /* PWM2H is controlled by PWM module */
IOCON2bits.PENL      = 0;  /* PWM2L is controlled by GPIO module */
IOCON2bits.PMOD      = 0;  /* Select Independent Output PWM mode */
PDC2 = 2000;               /* Initial Duty cycle */ 
DTR2    = 0;               /* Deadtime setting */
ALTDTR2 = 0;               /* Deadtime setting */
PHASE2 = 0;                /* */

PTCONbits.PTEN       = 1; /* Enable the PWM Module */
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to the write protection of IOCONxbits register.
I added the following line:

```
_FDEVOPT( PWMLOCK_OFF );
```

and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem with dspic33ev32GP002 and changed configuration bits like so:

```
// FDEVOPT
#pragma config PWMLOCK = OFF
```

This worked for me.